# In common-lisp how is the relation between types defined?

Tags: types, lisp, common-lisp

While playing in Lisp i noticed the following:

```
(subtypep 'string '(array character)) ==> NIL, T
(subtypep '(array character) 'string) ==> NIL, T
```

while

```
(typep (make-string x) '(array character)) ==> T
(typep (make-array x :element-type :character) 'string) ==>T
```

for any value of x.

Which means that "subtypep" says that 'string and '(array character) are two distinct types while "typep" says that **any instance of the one type is also an instance of the other** (1)

Unless (1) is not true -please give example-, why does this happen? I find it difficult to grasp because I assume that a type cannot conceptually exist without its instances, that is, it is defined by its instances: It is the class (in the mathematical sense) of objects that have a specific set of properties. Is this correct?

EDIT: As correctly pointed `(array character)` is not necessarily a subtype of `string`, for the simple reason of the existence of multi-dimensinal arrays of characters. But I still cant imagine an instance of `string` that has not a type of `(array character)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an implemntaiton issue:

```
ccl e$ rlwrap ./dx86cl64
Loading ~/ccl-init.lisp
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.7-dev-r14614M-trunk  (DarwinX8664)!
? (subtypep 'string '(array character))
T
T
?
```

Answer (score 3):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

Arrays in Common Lisp are mutable. Instead of attemping to pretend they're covariant or contravariant and adding complex dynamic checks, arrays in CL are invariant.  Thus, unless they are the same, there is no subtyping relationship between `(array character 1)` and `(array base-char 1)`.  Programs shouldn't store non-base characters in the latter, and programs could read a non-base character from the former.

Array upgrading causes further confusions for newcomers. It helps to keep in mind that, while some compilers use type declarations for safety, their primary goal is performance. Typed arrays are mapped (upgraded) to a set of specially-handled array element types.  These specialised array types must form a lattice (ensuring that we can sanely find the most specific specialised type), but there still no subtyping relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is some quirky thing in your implementation. (Possibly connected to some optimization).

For example in SBCL, if you `(describe 'string)`, you'll get `STRING names a primitive type-specifier: (undocumented)`. The interesting thing is that for `base-string` its the same, but:

```
(subtypep 'base-string 'array) => T
(subtypep 'base-string '(array base-char)) => T
(subtypep 'string 'array) => T
(subtypep 'string '(array character)) => NIL
(subtypep 'string '(array base-char)) => NIL
(subtypep 'string '(array standard-char)) => NIL
(subtypep 'string '(array extended-char)) => NIL
```

Comment: Base-string is subtype of (array base-char). What prevents string from being a subtype of (array character)?

Comment: The best place to get an answer to this question is, probably, sbcl-devel mailing list. It may be an optimization or a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(subtypep '(vector nil) 'string)
```

in SBCL and other implementations to understand. The requirement of (vector nil) being a subtype of string follows from the standard, even if base-char and character are equivalent in an implementation.